# Unmanaged Package overrides custom metadata

Tags: salesforcedx, custom-metadata

I have custom metadata with fields that would be only controlled by subscribers but whenever I have uploaded the new version of the package (sfdx package) in production, it overrides the existing value.

In the metadata configuration file, it is defined as this.

`<fieldManageability>SubscriberControlled</fieldManageability>`

this is the UI:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Field manageability only applies to managed packages.